# Can't log in to Google using HtmlUnit - Can't advance to web page for entering password

Tags: java, authentication, htmlunit, google-sites

Has anyone successfully logged into Google using HtmlUnit recently? I used to be able to, but since upgrading the BrowserVersion my WebClient uses, I am locked out. Many thanks if you can help me as I am really stuck!

I have been using BrowserVersion.CHROME from HtmlUnit-2.18. Login is a two-step process involving two forms. The first form has just the email field and the ‘Next’ button. After entering an email address and clicking ‘Next’, the second form displays. This form has the password field and the ‘Sign in’ button to complete the login process.

Here is the code I am using. myGoogleSitesHomeWebpage is still the login webpage when it should be my home web page:

```
HtmlTextInput email = (HtmlTextInput) webpage.getElementById("Email");
email.setValueAttribute("MyEmailAddress");
HtmlSubmitInput nextButton = webpage.getElementById("next");
newWebpage  = clickElement(nextButton);
webclient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(8000);
HtmlPasswordInput password = (HtmlPasswordInput) newWebpage.getElementById("Passwd-hidden");
password.setValueAttribute("MyPassword");
HtmlSubmitInput signInButton = newWebpage.getElementById("signIn");
myGoogleSitesHomeWebpage  = clickElement(signInButton);
webclient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(8000);
```

clickElement(nextButton) does not advance to the second form with the ‘Sign in’ button.  It has my Google Sites web page I am trying to log into and my email correctly set up in the second form, but still with the link showing ‘Next’. I also think the input elements  id="Email” and id="Passwd-hidden” are wrong and should be id="Email-hidden” and id="Passwd”. It seems that the second form I get is still the one for entering the email address and not the one for entering the password. Here are the relevant parts of the second form:

```
<form novalidate="" method="post" action="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth" id="gaia_loginform">
<input name="continue" type="hidden" value="https://sites.google.com/site/MyGoogleSitesHomePageAddress"/>
<input id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" value="MyEmailAddress" spellcheck="false" autofocus=""/>
<input id="Passwd-hidden" type="password" spellcheck="false" class="hidden"/>
<input id="next" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Next"/>
<input id="signIn" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Sign in"/>
</form>
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and show me the code I should be using to do the complete login process? Many thanks, that would help me so much!

Comment: I've had the same problem, look here I've posted the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461077/htmlunit-google-login/33463832#33463832

Comment: The problem solved itself: very strange! Having given up on finding a solution I returned a month later to find that login worked perfectly without me having made any changes to my code. Login has now been working OK for 2 months. I can only suppose that changes made by Google to how they process login made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It works with me with CHROME BrowserVersion.

Below is the complete case, which also gives 'OK'

```
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
        HtmlAnchor a = page.getHtmlElementById("gb_70");
        page = a.click();
        HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page.getElementById("gaia_loginform");
        HtmlTextInput email = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("Email");
        email.setValueAttribute(myEmailAddress);
        HtmlSubmitInput nextButton = page.getHtmlElementById("next");
        System.out.println(nextButton.asXml());
        HtmlPage newWebpage = nextButton.click();
        String status = newWebpage.getWebResponse().getStatusMessage();
        System.out.println(status);
    }
```

Comment: Ahmed, thanks for your fast reply! I have tried your suggestion but still no success. Check the edits I’ve made to my question above.
What would be a great help is if you could show me the code you use to go through the complete  login process: from entry of your email address, then entry of your password until you have managed to get to one of your Google web pages as a logged in user.
Many thanks!

Comment: `getInputByValue` is locale dependent, that why I didn't use, please check updated reply

Comment: I changed my code (see above) to use getHtmlElementById rather than getInputByValue for the buttons as you suggested, but it is still not working. Can you show me what my code should be?