# HtmlUnit Google Login

Tags: java-7, htmlunit

I want to automated the google login and accept oauth to get the authentication code.

I get a NullPointerExeption by nextButton.click(), I can't find the "next" Button.

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); //BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?");            

        HtmlTextInput email = (HtmlTextInput)page.getElementById("Email");
        email.setValueAttribute(emailAddress);
        HtmlSubmitInput nextButton = (HtmlSubmitInput)page.getElementById("next");

        HtmlPage newPage = (HtmlPage)nextButton.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(8000);

        HtmlTextInput passwd = (HtmlTextInput)page.getElementById("Passwd");
        passwd.setValueAttribute(password);
        HtmlSubmitInput signIn = (HtmlSubmitInput)page.getElementById("signIn");

        HtmlPage pageSucces = (HtmlPage)signIn.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(8000);

        HtmlSubmitInput submitAccess = (HtmlSubmitInput)page.getElementById("submit_approve_access");
        HtmlPage pageAccess = (HtmlPage)submitAccess.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(8000);

        HtmlTextInput code = (HtmlTextInput)page.getElementById("code");
        System.out.println(code.getText());
```

I've tried this [Can't log in to Google using HtmlUnit - Can't advance to web page for entering password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31851430/cant-log-in-to-google-using-htmlunit-cant-advance-to-web-page-for-entering-p)
without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the website, the html page is not like the standard browser. The login page looks like this: https://lh6.ggpht.com/v19i1LtG-IdZKSZ-rhtuflJJmVmZM3gd3uauQQyLFvJxXTxYi4t8ygCQXwutu1nq69mmna8=w351

You can also look into the page object there you can see the idMap with all available IDs.

```
        HtmlTextInput email = (HtmlTextInput)page.getElementById("Email");
        email.setValueAttribute(emailAddress);
        HtmlPasswordInput passwd = (HtmlPasswordInput)page.getElementById("Passwd");
        passwd.setValueAttribute(password);
        HtmlSubmitInput signInButton = (HtmlSubmitInput)page.getElementById("signIn");

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(8000);
        HtmlPage newPage = (HtmlPage)signInButton.click();
```